# Add two different column values as an attribute into the the already JSON formated column which already have data. SQL Server

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

Existing Data

```
{ "Attr1": "AAAAAAAAA", "Attr2": 70, "Attr3": null, "Attr4": false }
```

I want to insert in below format right after the `Attr2`
both exists

```
"NewAttr": { "SourceTable1.Column1": "12xx12", "SourceTable2.Column2": "0192xx" }
```

Column1 exists but not Column2

```
"NewAttr": { "SourceTable1.Column1": "12xx12" }
```

Column2 exists but not Column1

```
"NewAttr": { "SourceTable2.Column2": "0192xx" }
```

None exist

```
"NewAttr": {}

SELECT top 10000 JSON_MODIFY(dt.DestinationColumn, '$.NewAttr', st.Column1) 
FROM dbo.Joiningtable jt 
INNER JOIN dbo.DestinationTable dt ON dt.ID = jt.TID 
INNER JOIN dbo.SourceTable st ON jt.TID = st.ID
```

I am not able to get the point to add nested attr as I showed in example.

I was trying to write the first select statement so that I can see results are correctly append. but as a final result, I need to update `DestinationTable.DestinationColumn`

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: Maybe this will help us collaborate on a solution https://dbfiddle.uk/Tp-9lSk-

Comment: What do you mean column1 exist but not column2? Columns always exist, especially if you have INNER JOIN

Comment: Maybe its related to Col1 and Col2 being NULL?  https://dbfiddle.uk/fkP0xgRe

Comment: These are cases here column mean column value from SourceTable. I am having inner join based on ID. Attributes are different they may be blank.

Answer (score 0):

You could either use nested `JSON_MODIFY` calls:

```sql
SELECT
  JSON_MODIFY(
    JSON_MODIFY(
      JSON_MODIFY(
        dt.DestinationColumn,
        '$.NewAttr',
        JSON_QUERY('{}')
      ),
      '$.NewAttr."SourceTable.Column1"',
      st.Column1
    ),
    '$.NewAttr."SourceTable.Column2"',
    st.Column2
  )
FROM dbo.Joiningtable jt 
INNER JOIN dbo.DestinationTable dt on dt.ID = jt.TID 
INNER JOIN dbo.SourceTable st on jt.TID = st.ID;
```

Or you could generate the whole nested object in an `APPLY` and insert it at once:

```sql
SELECT
  JSON_MODIFY(dt.DestinationColumn, '$.NewAttr', JSON_QUERY(j.NewAttr))
FROM dbo.Joiningtable jt 
INNER JOIN dbo.DestinationTable dt on dt.ID = jt.TID 
INNER JOIN dbo.SourceTable st on jt.TID = st.ID
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT
      [SourceTable.Column1] = st.Column1,
      [SourceTable.Column2] = st.Column2
    FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
) j(NewAttr);
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/oOTvgC6k)

Comment: Thanks your logic works for me but there is a small part that I am trying to add when both column1 and column2 are null then it should add like NewAttr: {}.
I tried below  logic but don't know it is adding '\' in my json string
JSON_MODIFY(dt.DestinationColumn, '$.NewAttr', 
        CASE WHEN j.NewAttr IS NOT NULL THEN j.NewAttr
             ELSE N'{}'
        END
    ) AS ModifiedColumn

Comment: Just do it like I showed (I removed the `WHERE` filter) you don't need that `CASE`. If it's escaping it and you know it's definitely valid JSON then do `JSON_QUERY(CASE ... END)`

Answer (score 0):

I used nested case expressions

```
CREATE TABLE SourceTable
(
  ID int,
  Column1 nvarchar(max),
  Column2 nvarchar(max)
)  
  
CREATE TABLE DestinationTable
(
  ID int,
  DestinationColumn nvarchar(max)
)

CREATE TABLE Joiningtable
(
  TID int
)    

INSERT INTO   SourceTable (ID, Column1,Column2) Values
  (1,'12xx12','0192xx'),
  (2,'12xx12',NULL),
  (3,NULL,'0192xx'),
  (4,NULL,NULL);

INSERT INTO   DestinationTable (ID, DestinationColumn) Values
  (1,'{"Attr1":"AAAAAAAAA","Attr2":70,"Attr3":null,"Attr4":false}'),
  (2,'{"Attr1":"AAAAAAAAA","Attr2":70,"Attr3":null,"Attr4":false}'),
  (3,'{"Attr1":"AAAAAAAAA","Attr2":70,"Attr3":null,"Attr4":false}'),
  (4,'{"Attr1":"AAAAAAAAA","Attr2":70,"Attr3":null,"Attr4":false}');

INSERT INTO  Joiningtable (TID) Values 
  (1),
  (2),
  (3),
  (4);
   
SELECT * FROM SourceTable
SELECT * FROM DestinationTable
SELECT * FROM Joiningtable
  
SELECT top 10000 
  CASE  WHEN st.Column1 IS NULL THEN   CASE  WHEN st.Column2 IS NULL THEN        'Both empty'     ELSE       'Only Col 2 exists'     END
  ELSE  CASE  WHEN st.Column2 IS NULL THEN 'Only Col 1 exists' ELSE 'Both Col 1 and 2 exists' END
  END as scenario,

  CASE  WHEN st.Column1 IS NULL THEN 
    CASE  WHEN st.Column2 IS NULL THEN  
       JSON_MODIFY(dt.DestinationColumn, '$.NewAttr',JSON_QUERY('{}'))
    ELSE 
        JSON_MODIFY(dt.DestinationColumn,'$.NewAttr','SourceTable.Column2": "' + st.Column2)     
    END
  ELSE  
    CASE  WHEN st.Column2 IS NULL THEN 
      JSON_MODIFY(dt.DestinationColumn,'$.NewAttr','SourceTable.Column1": "' + st.Column1) 
    ELSE 
       JSON_MODIFY(dt.DestinationColumn,'$.NewAttr','SourceTable.Column1": "' + st.Column1 + '":SourceTable.Column2": "' + st.Column2)  
    END
  END as DestinationColumn
  
FROM dbo.Joiningtable jt 
INNER JOIN dbo.DestinationTable dt on dt.ID = jt.TID 
INNER JOIN dbo.SourceTable st on jt.TID = st.ID
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/-1bWvPMM)

| scenario | DestinationColumn |
| --- | --- |
| Col1 & Col2 | {"Attr1":"AAAAAAAAA","Attr2":70,"Attr3":null,"Attr4":false,"NewAttr":"SourceTable.Column1": "12xx12":SourceTable.Column2": "0192xx"} |
| Only Col1 | {"Attr1":"AAAAAAAAA","Attr2":70,"Attr3":null,"Attr4":false,"NewAttr":"SourceTable.Column1": "12xx12"} |
| Only Col2 | {"Attr1":"AAAAAAAAA","Attr2":70,"Attr3":null,"Attr4":false,"NewAttr":"SourceTable.Column2": "0192xx"} |
| Both empty | {"Attr1":"AAAAAAAAA","Attr2":70,"Attr3":null,"Attr4":false,"NewAttr":{}} |